# SID is not returned in set-cookie header in Flutter WEB

Tags: node.js, flutter, express-session

I wanted to know how to retrieve the session id stored in the set-cookie on the web version of flutter? On the mobile versions the session id is retrieved from the set-cookie header, but on the web version it returns null.

My express session configuration on node.js :

```
app.use(session({
    // Key to sign session ID cookie
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    // Force session to be saved back to the session store
    resave: false,
    // Save session even if it is not initialized
    saveUninitialized: false,
    // // Session cookie
    cookie: { 
        // Configuration for HTTPS only
        secure: false, 
        // Configuration for HTTP only
        httpOnly: true,
        // Session expiration time
        maxAge: 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 7 hours
        // Session path
        path: '/',
    },
    // Store configuration
    store: sequelizeSessionStore,
}))
```

My cors configuration for node.js :

```
const cors = CORS({
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type',
})
```

My login method on node.js :

```
loginRouter.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    // Get email and password from request body
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // Check if email and password are empty
    if (!email || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            title: 'Empty',
            message: 'Email and password are required',
        });
    }

    // Login function
    const user = await login(email, password)

    // If user not found, return 404
    if(!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            title: 'Invalid credentials',
            message: 'Email or password is incorrect',
        });
    }

    // Set user session
    req.session.userId = user.id;

    // Return success
    return res.status(200).json({
        title: 'Success',
        message: 'You are logged in',
    });
});
```

My function acts with my api on Flutter

```
Future<void> loginAPI(String email, String password, Function clearControllers, Function(bool) isError, Function(String) errorText) async {
    try {
      // Send request to API with email and password in body
      final response = await client.post(
        Uri.parse(apiURL.getLoginURL()),
        body: {
          "email": email,
          "password": password,
        },
      );

      return handleResponse(response, clearControllers, isError, errorText);
    } catch (e) {
      return authInternalErrorMsg(isError, errorText);
    }
  }
```

and my answer is a success where the session ID is retrieved and stored in Flutter's secure storage :

```
Future<void> handleResponse(http.Response response, Function clearControllers, Function(bool) isError, Function(String) errorText) async {
    // Get response data
    final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    // Get title
    final String title = responseData['title'];
    // Get response headers
    final headers = response.headers;

    // Check response data
    if (title == "Success") {
      // Get cookie
      final cookie = headers['set-cookie'];
      print(cookie);

      // Check if cookie is not null
      if (cookie != null) {
        // Delete previous cookie in secure storage
        await cookieStorageServices.deletePreviouslyCookie();

        // Save cookie in secure storage
        await cookieStorageServices.saveCookie(cookie);

        // Get session validity
        final sessionIsValid = await cookieStorageServices.readCookie();

        // Check if session is valid
        if (sessionIsValid != null) {
          // Session is valid action
          return sessionIsValidAction(clearControllers);
        }
      } else {
        // Active error message
        isError(true);
        // Set error message
        errorText("Unable to retrieve the login cookie, please contact support");
      }
    } else if (title == "Invalid credentials") {
      return invalidCredentialsMsg(isError, errorText);
    }
  }
```

expected print output :

```
connect.sid=...; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 18 Jul 2023 21:10:33 GMT; HttpOnly
```

output obtained :

```
null
```

thank you for your answers